# Visual Studio Code Angular/Node: prevent debugger from stepping into library code

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

I have an Angular (CLI version 8.3.8) app running on node.js that I'm building in Visual Studio Code in TypeScript .  When I debug, I want the debugger to only step into my TypeScript code.  Instead, it always wants to step into the JavaScript code in the various libraries that the app is using.

How do I prevent this?  How do I make sure that I only step into my TypeScript code?  Effectively what I'm looking for is an equivalent to the full-blown Visual Studio's "Just my Code" functionality.

Comment: Have you tried this "skip files" feature? As referenced here: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_8#_node-debugging

Answer (score 2):

The comment from @jfarleyx answered my question.  https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_8#_node-debugging

Comment: Happy to hear it helped!